# How to test Date picker component in jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs, enzyme

I am completely new to React and jest.
I have a react component with two date field also button which I want to test using jest frameworks. As I said I am completely new in both React and jest if anyone can give an example I will really appreciate.

here is my component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DayPickerInput from 'react-day-picker/DayPickerInput';
import 'react-day-picker/lib/style.css';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { Container, Col, Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button, } from 'reactstrap';

class Aquaculturedatepicker extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      dateFrom: '',
      dateTo: '',
      loading: false,
    };
  }

  handleFirstDayChange = (dateFrom) => {
    this.setState({ dateFrom });

  }

  handleSecondDayChange = (dateTo) => {
    this.setState({ dateTo });
  }

  onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const dateFrom = this.state.dateFrom
    const dateTo = this.state.dateTo
    this.setState({ loading: true })
    this.props.onDateChange(dateFrom, dateTo);
  }

  render() {
    // console.log('hello', this.state.dateFrom)
    // console.log('hello', this.state.dateTo)
    const { dateFrom, dateTo } = this.state;
    return (<Container className="Datepickerfrom" style={{ width: "1000px", paddingTop: "2px", paddingBottom: "60px" }}>
              <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit.bind(this)} inline>
                  <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                      <Label style={{ paddingRight: "5px", margin: "0.2", fontSize: "20px" }}>Date From</Label>
                      <DayPickerInput value={dateFrom} onDayChange={this.handleFirstDayChange} inputProps={{ required: false }} />
                  </FormGroup>
                  </Col>
                  <Col>
                  <FormGroup>
                      <Label style={{ paddingRight: "5px", margin: "0.2em", fontSize: "20px" }}>Date To</Label>
                      <DayPickerInput value={dateTo} onDayChange={this.handleSecondDayChange} inputProps={{ required: false }} />
                  </FormGroup>
                  </Col>
                  <Button className="btn-lg btn-primary" style={{ padding: "6px", margin: "0.2em", fontSize: "20px", backgroundColor: "#008CBA", border: "none" }}>
                      <i className="far fa-calendar-alt"></i> Submit
                  </Button>
              </Form>
          </Container>)
  }
}
export default Aquaculturedatepicker;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you need to test is that you can enter values into the `DayPicker` components and that `onDateChange` is called with the values you have entered when the get submitted.

```
const onDateChange = jest.fn()
const component = shallow(<Aquaculturedatepicker onDateChange={onDateChange} />) 

const dayPickers = component.find('DayPickerInput')
dayPickers.at(0).prop('onDayChange')('date1')
dayPickers.at(1).prop('onDayChange')('date2')


component.find('Form').simulate('submit')
expect(onDateChange).toHaveBeenCalledWith('date1', 'date2')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Andreas Köberle it works really appreciate.